# How do I change the recent iOS App Icon from Unity or Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an app made with Unity, however when I build it from Xcode right on to my iPad I still have the Unity logo when you double click the home button and find recent apps

See image for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OY12.jpg

I've tried finding every possible icon change function in the Unity project as well as the Xcode project.

This most likely has nothing to do with the code of the file, since it's pre-compiled by Unity.

I would like to get this icon to have the same icon as my launch icon and app store icon. All of those work fine.

I was wondering if this maybe had something to with the app being loaded straight from Xcode and not from the App Store.

I hope you guys can help me fix this problem! :-)

Comment: Try deleting the app from your iPad and then restart your iPad device so that no cache remains. Once restarted, install the app from Xcode.

Comment: @Saif that indeed turned out to be the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: Okay I will post it as an answer. Please mark and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because iOS devices do not delete the cache once you delete the application. Due to this, icon and even the splash images remain the old one. Try deleting the app from your iPad and then restart your iPad device so that no cache remains. Once restarted, install the app from Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of cache.

Try to clean build. That should help you.